# cakephp 3.0 validation numeric value is not known

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
->add(
    'mobile',
    [
        'unique' => [
            'rule' => 'validateUnique',
            'provider' => 'table',
            'message' => 'Mobile Already exist choose other mobile'
        ]
    ]
)
```

Above is the code in cake 2.0 we can add rule 1 and rule2 but in cake 3.0 I am facing problem.

I want to add rules for mobile number it has to be numeric and validate unique can anyone suggest me how to write two rules and two message?

Comment: The snippet looks more like 3.x than 2.x. Anyways, check the docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#marking-rules-as-the-last-to-run**

Comment: ->add('mobile', ['unique' => ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table','message' => 'Mobile Already exist choose other mobile']]) I am using this code but I am getting Unknown method "numeric" this error how to validate only number

Comment: The code you are showing here will not trigger any such error. Please make sure that you are showing the _actual_ code that you are using, _all_ of it (and please update your question instead of adding code in the comments)!